# How we can monitor the size and impact of "Living Latin Community"

Tags: contemporary-latin, modern-life, statistics

By "Living Latin community" I refer principally to those individuals who want to use Latin language in the actual-life for whatever reason they have (the main reason is probably in order to learn).

With the increasing popularity of the natural-method for Latin teaching in recent years, it has been claimed that there are more people interested in using the language. There are indeed several groups that you can communicate in Latin.

I would like to trace this trend, if it exists at all. There are two main branches that this trend should be manifested:

1. Off-line branch: number of Living Latin programs and participants.
2. On-line branch: namely to seek for the presence of Latin online. Trying to get the number of Latin pages might be interesting, but I'm not sure how to find it and exclude old quotes of books. And using Wikipedia stats for page-views and number of editors might be more promising idea ([to get a glimpse](https://pageviews.toolforge.org/topviews/?project=la.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&date=yesterday&excludes=) of that option).

would like to hear your ideas.